# Apostol theorem 1.35(Every nonnegative real number a has a unique nonnegative square root.) Is it necessary that there exists such a number?

Tags: calculus, analysis

[image]

In theorem 1.35 of Apostol's Calculus, he states that we may choose a number $c$, such that $c<b$ and $c<(a-b^2)/3b$. My question is, must we have such a number $c$? Can for some values of $a$ and $b$, $c$ not exist at all? If not, how do I prove that c will exist, merely with the assertion that $b^2<a$? I can't seem to get anywhere with the inequalities, so help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since $b>0$ and $d:=(a-b^2)/(3b)>0,$ we have $e:=\min(b,d)>0.$ You can then choose $c:=e/2.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks really. Seems like I missed a silly thing.

Comment: Given any number $~r > 0,~$ you can always find a number $~s,~$ such that $~0 < s < r.~$  One example is taking $~s = r/2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I copy-paste my early comment here as an answer.)

Since $b>0$
and $d:=(a−b^2)/(3b)>0$,
we have $e:=\min(b,d)>0$.
You can then choose $c:=e/2$.

Answer (score 0):

To actually provide an answer to your question and not just a comment, since $b>0$ and $b^2<a$, we have that $\frac{a-b^2}{3b}\neq 0$. Let $\varepsilon = \min \left\{ b, \frac{a-b^2}{3b}\right\}$. Then $0< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$, so such a $c$ exists.